# Want to split a product name and rating from a string in python

Tags: python, string

I want to split this string and many others like it. They all are information about a product and its ratings, with the product name at front and the rating at the very end.

`"Moooni Modern Rectangular Raindrop Crystal Chandelier Ceiling Lighting Fixture Rectangle Pendant Flush Mount LED Light for Dining Room L 40x W 12x H 31.54.8 out of 5"`

The ratings for every product are different, so I have to split them like this:

```
actual rating = float()
for price in catalogue:
    priceslicer = price.split("{actualrating} out of 5")
    pr1 = priceslicer[0]
    pr2 = priceslicer[1]
```

However, as you can see, this becomes a problem with strings like the one above, where the review is right after some numbers. How do I split the string so I get the actual rating (4.8 out of 5) and not an error from '31.54.8'?

Comment: This looks like data from web scraping! If so there is a way to allow breaks,` <p> or <br>`. Is it from web scraping text?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I'm webscraping from Amazon and I want to separate the names from their respective reviews. How can I use breaks to do this?

Comment: In place where you get the text. Instead of just `.text` use `.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')`

Answer (score 0):

First, check the data at the source and if you can get a way out as suggested above, then that is your best bet. Secondly, if you don't have any control over that, and you are sure that your lines are ending with "out of 5" and your ratings are from 0.0 to 9.9, then you can use below regular expression.

```
import re
re.search(r"(\d(.\d)?) out of 5$", s)
```

Answer (score -1):

Where are you getting your Strings from? If it is from a database can you assign them a different field in said database. Or is it from a list? If it is from a list can you maybe think about using list in list?
e.g.

```
catalogue = [["Moooni Modern Rectangular Raindrop Crystal Chandelier Ceiling Lighting Fixture Rectangle Pendant Flush Mount LED Light for Dining Room L 40x W 12x H 31.5", 4.8][...other product, other rating]]
```

I've done it this way in a past project and it worked wonders.

Comment: This is a comment requesting clarification more than an answer

Comment: Yes, my strings are from a list. What is the code for doing the method above, iterating over many strings? I have a lot of strings in the list and I need to do this for all of them.